# Cómo pasar una variable por referencia en DART

Tags: funciones, dart

¿Cómo puedo pasar una variable por referencia a una función en lenguaje dart? No he encontrado una respuesta clara, simplemente sugieren utilizar una clase ya que por defecto se pasan por referencia ¿No está soportado por el lenguaje?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente no es posible, la única manera es usar una clase 'wrapper' que se encargaría de contener tu variable, en Dart, como en algunos otros lenguages, los objetos se pasan por referencia.

Revisa este enlace.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258267/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-primitive-parameter-by-reference-in-dart

Comment: Es válido que traduzcas la respuesta y dejes el enlace para dar créditos al autor y ayudas a que tu aporte mejore de calidad